# Using If Statements in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a script of batch (modeled after Joshua in "War Games")

```
@echo off
color 0b
echo Greetings, Professor Falken
set /p interface =
echo Would You Like to Play a Game?
set /p ifGame =
if /i "%ifGame%" =="yes" goto yesgame
if /i "%ifGame%" =="no" goto nogame
:yesgame
echo List of Games
echo chess
echo Poker
echo Fighter Combat
echo Guerilla Warfare
echo Desert Warfare
echo Air-to-Ground Actions
echo Theaterwide Tactical Warfare
echo Theaterwide Biotoxic and Chemical Warfare
echo Global Thermonuclear War
pause
echo Which game would you like to play?
set /p WhichGame =
pause
exit
:nogame
set /p areYouSure=Are You Sure? 
pause
exit
```

But, when I enter "No" it still shows the list of games...

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the spaces between the variable name and the `=` symbol when using `set /p`. From:

```
set /p ifGame =
```

To:

```
set /p ifGame=
```

Otherwise the variable you set has a space at the end of the name. So `%ifGame%` expands to nothing, whereas `%ifGame %` will expand to the correct value.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to make small mistakes like that in Batch. Especially coming from something like Python. Batch is very simple and will most often interpret white-space. No problem.

Comment: @DannyP24 Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it worked for you.